# Loop through different databases and union select specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number of databases with the same table name with the same columns from the same server.

There is 1 table from each database that i need to combine together to create a report.

is there a way i can go through each database and find the tables i want to combine i.e "tblJoin" and union them together without having to hardcode it i.e looping?

Comment: You could use some dynamic SQL to create the `UNION ALL` query, however, will you be adding (and removing) databases often with this set up? If not, I'd say hardcoding a `VIEW` is the better option, as using a `CURSOR` or `sp_MSforeachdb` to query the `sys` objects to create a dynamic statement is likely going to be more of a performance burden than a benefit. And the performance will only degrade the more databases you have,

Answer (score 0):

If you have the misfortune of having to deal with *multiple databases* that are structured in this way, then I would not attempt to do any sort of union between them.  In a past life – after making certain that the database in question could actually do this – I successfully accomplished this task using a **stored procedure** (and a "temporary table") on one of the systems.

(And I purposely put that stored-proc on a "reporting" database because I must say that the other databases "took a mighty hit" when the proc ran, and the "reporting" database was impacted most of all.  There was absolutely nothing "pretty" about it.  But ... it *did* get the job done, within the cumbersome limits of the reporting engine I was obliged to use.)